# Executing a command from TCL script

Tags: tcl

The below command works fine when i run it from unix box, but when I execute it from a tcl script its not working. please help me how to execute the command.

```
java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml
```

I have tried the following lines of code

```
exec "java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml"

eval "java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml"
```

Comment: Please add the error that you get the next time too.

Comment: Actually, it works fine when you run it from a UNIX **shell**. The shell splits the string into words. If you for some reason need the services of a shell for starting `java`, use e.g. `exec sh -c "java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml"`, otherwise see Johannes answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use separate arguments.

```
exec java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml
```

I'm not sure if [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) looks in the path, so it is better do do the following:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok java] diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml
```

Or if you are on 8.4 (which is end of life by the way)

```
eval [linsert {exec diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml} 1 [auto_execok java]]
```

Comment: FYI, `exec` most certainly _does_ use the path.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do it:

```
exec java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml
```

No quotes; each Tcl word becomes a separate argument.

```
set command "java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml"
exec {*}$command
# or in 8.4 and before, one of these:
# eval exec $command
# eval [list exec] [lrange $command 0 end]
# eval [linsert $command 0 exec]
```

Or, if you prefer shell syntax to Tcl syntax:

```
set command "java -jar diffkit-0.9.0/diffkit-app.jar -planfiles plan.xml"
exec /bin/sh -c $command
```

This last one is very useful when you need to do complex redirections; they're currently easier to do in the Bourne shell (and its derivatives) than in Tcl. It (probably) won't work on Windows though; the equivalent with firing stuff through `CMD.EXE` is unfortunately a bit horrible.

Comment: Usually, when you use windows, use `cmd.exe /c ...` or even `cmd.exe /c start {} ...`